# Can't create new post. rest_cookie_invalid_nonce no matter what I do

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin, wordpress-6

Today I decided to write 2 articles in a row and I always schedule my posts.

However, somethig bad had happened and now I can't add any new article to my wordpress.

Even after logging in in different browsers, or in incognito mode, I get errors when saving the draft.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Cookie verification failed

```json
{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"A verifica\u00e7\u00e3o cookie falhou","data":{"status":403}}
```

and

```json
{"code":"wp_die","message":"Este link expirou.<\/p><p><a href=\"\/blog\/wp-admin\/post-new.php\">Tente novamente.<\/a>","data":{"status":403},"additional_errors":[]}
```

Another thing I noticed is that I'm now getting an error saying my cookies are disabled the first time I try to sign in.
[image]

Wp version: 6.0

Any help is appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klO8g.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VWXt.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had a problem with my Cloudflare's configuration, which was caching the admin area by mistake.